# Choose appropriate level for UIWindow to enable interaction with controllers behind it

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

I have created a `UIWindow` to show a menu floating over all controllers *globally*. I want to set the level such that window is always visible plus user can interact with controllers behind it. Window contains a controller which will expand/contract on user tap. See the pictures below:

[image]  [image]

Currently, I have tried following approach:

```
UIWindow *statusWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
statusWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert; //Have tried all three
statusWindow.hidden = NO;

[statusWindow addSubview:_gmDemo.view];//my controller's view
[statusWindow bringSubviewToFront:_gmDemo.view];
```

This code blocks my interaction with controllers behind it. Moreover, when I set it to `UIWindowLevelNormal - 1`, window is hidden but I can interact with other controllers.

Please tell me correct way to achieve my goal. Thanks.

**Note:** I have already read [this](http://shaune.com.au/using-multiple-uiwindows-in-ios-applications/) post.

Comment: To which window/ViewController did you add "statusWindow" object?

Comment: Sorry don't remember. It was almost 3+ years back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution myself. Problem was UIWindow's frame as well as level. First I set level to `UIWindowLevelNormal`. Secondly, I have handled window's frame dynamically on menu's button tap. When menu need to be expand/contract, I appropriately increase/decrease size of UIWindow on delegate's call. That's it.